# Perl Grep Exclusion

Tags: perl, grep

I'm grepping values for a list of legitimate file names but there are certain file name matches I'm trying to exclude. I can't quite figure out the exclusions.

```
List = (  
"fileA",  
"Makefile.am.cppcheck",  
"Makefile.am.cpplint",  
"README-autotools.md",  
"README-metrics.md",  
"README.md",  
"autogen.sh",  
"configure.ac",  
"test.pl",  
)  

@files = grep(/(?!readme|makefile)([a-z]\.[a-z])/i,@list);
```

The grep works fine without the exclusion but what am I missing to exclude items matching (readme|makefile) or other patterns?

EDIT: My filenames must include a period (such as test.pl), hence the reason for exclusions as opposed to weeding out the unwanted names alone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the "magic regex" again, that's expected to move the earth in a single pattern

It's hard to tell from your question what result you want, but it looks like you want any file that has a dot in its name that doesn't start with `readme` or `makefile`

So just write that. After all, that's how `.gitignore` works: it's just a list of files or file patterns to ignore, it's not one long super-complicated glob expression

This way others, and you yourself in six months' time, will be able to make out what your code does

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my @list = qw/
    fileA  
    Makefile.am.cppcheck  
    Makefile.am.cpplint  
    README-autotools.md  
    README-metrics.md  
    README.md  
    autogen.sh  
    configure.ac  
    test.pl  
/;

my @filtered = grep {
    /\./ and not /^readme/i and not /^makefile/i;
} @list;

say for @filtered;
```

#### output

```
autogen.sh
configure.ac
test.pl
```

Comment: Ty Borodin. That was the syntax I was trying to find. I was unaware of the 'and not' expression.

Comment: @user3425900: It's a very ordinary scalar expression, not confined to use within `grep`. You may be more familiar with `&&` and `!` but they make me spit

Comment: I'm accustomed to it in BASH but first time I've seen it in perl. Good to know!